# How to prevent Vim from clearing the system clipboard (:reg +) on exit?

Tags: normal-mode, visual-mode, os-clipboard

After copying text to the system keyboard clipboard in `vim`, I'm unable to paste the text after exiting `vim`.

I find this behavior frustrating, since I often copy text in files to paste it on the command-line, and this is currently not possible without opening two tabs in the terminal or using a terminal multiplexer (e.g. `tmux`).

```
" system clipboard: CLIPBOARD (+)
noremap <leader>y "+y
```

How can I prevent `vim` from clearing the system clipboard on exit?

**`vim --version`**:

```
$ vim --version
VIM - Vi IMproved 8.1 (2018 May 18, compiled Jun 15 2019 16:41:15)
Included patches: 1-875, 878, 884, 948, 1046, 1365-1368, 1382, 1401
Modified by team+vim@tracker.debian.org
Compiled by team+vim@tracker.debian.org
Huge version with GTK3 GUI.  Features included (+) or not (-):
+acl               +extra_search      +mouse_netterm     +tag_old_static
+arabic            +farsi             +mouse_sgr         -tag_any_white
+autocmd           +file_in_path      -mouse_sysmouse    +tcl
+autochdir         +find_in_path      +mouse_urxvt       +termguicolors
-autoservername    +float             +mouse_xterm       +terminal
+balloon_eval      +folding           +multi_byte        +terminfo
+balloon_eval_term -footer            +multi_lang        +termresponse
+browse            +fork()            -mzscheme          +textobjects
++builtin_terms    +gettext           +netbeans_intg     +textprop
+byte_offset       -hangul_input      +num64             +timers
+channel           +iconv             +packages          +title
+cindent           +insert_expand     +path_extra        +toolbar
+clientserver      +job               +perl              +user_commands
+clipboard         +jumplist          +persistent_undo   +vartabs
+cmdline_compl     +keymap            +postscript        +vertsplit
+cmdline_hist      +lambda            +printer           +virtualedit
+cmdline_info      +langmap           +profile           +visual
+comments          +libcall           -python            +visualextra
+conceal           +linebreak         +python3           +viminfo
+cryptv            +lispindent        +quickfix          +vreplace
+cscope            +listcmds          +reltime           +wildignore
+cursorbind        +localmap          +rightleft         +wildmenu
+cursorshape       +lua               +ruby              +windows
+dialog_con_gui    +menu              +scrollbind        +writebackup
+diff              +mksession         +signs             +X11
+digraphs          +modify_fname      +smartindent       -xfontset
+dnd               +mouse             +startuptime       +xim
-ebcdic            +mouseshape        +statusline        +xpm
+emacs_tags        +mouse_dec         -sun_workshop      +xsmp_interact
+eval              +mouse_gpm         +syntax            +xterm_clipboard
+ex_extra          -mouse_jsbterm     +tag_binary        -xterm_save
   system vimrc file: "$VIM/vimrc"
     user vimrc file: "$HOME/.vimrc"
 2nd user vimrc file: "~/.vim/vimrc"
      user exrc file: "$HOME/.exrc"
  system gvimrc file: "$VIM/gvimrc"
    user gvimrc file: "$HOME/.gvimrc"
2nd user gvimrc file: "~/.vim/gvimrc"
       defaults file: "$VIMRUNTIME/defaults.vim"
    system menu file: "$VIMRUNTIME/menu.vim"
  fall-back for $VIM: "/usr/share/vim"
Compilation: gcc -c -I. -Iproto -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -DFEAT_GUI_GTK  -pthread -I/usr/include/gtk-3.0 -I/usr/include/at-spi2-atk/2.0 -I/usr/include/at-spi-2.0 -I/usr/include/dbus-1.0 -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dbus-1.0/include -I/usr/include/gtk-3.0 -I/usr/include/gio-unix-2.0 -I/usr/include/cairo -I/usr/include/libdrm -I/usr/include/pango-1.0 -I/usr/include/harfbuzz -I/usr/include/pango-1.0 -I/usr/include/fribidi -I/usr/include/atk-1.0 -I/usr/include/cairo -I/usr/include/pixman-1 -I/usr/include/freetype2 -I/usr/include/libpng16 -I/usr/include/gdk-pixbuf-2.0 -I/usr/include/libmount -I/usr/include/blkid -I/usr/include/uuid -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/glib-2.0/include -Wdate-time  -g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/vim-4Pursk/vim-8.1.0875=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=1
Linking: gcc   -L. -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now -fstack-protector -rdynamic -Wl,-export-dynamic -Wl,-E  -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now -Wl,--as-needed -o vim   -lgtk-3 -lgdk-3 -lpangocairo-1.0 -lpango-1.0 -latk-1.0 -lcairo-gobject -lcairo -lgdk_pixbuf-2.0 -lgio-2.0 -lgobject-2.0 -lglib-2.0 -lSM -lICE -lXpm -lXt -lX11 -lXdmcp -lSM -lICE  -lm -ltinfo -lnsl  -lselinux  -lacl -lattr -lgpm -ldl  -L/usr/lib -llua5.2 -Wl,-E  -fstack-protector-strong -L/usr/local/lib  -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl/5.28/CORE -lperl -ldl -lm -lpthread -lcrypt  -L/usr/lib/python3.7/config-3.7m-x86_64-linux-gnu -lpython3.7m -lcrypt -lpthread -ldl -lutil -lm -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -ltcl8.6 -ldl -lz -lpthread -lm -lruby-2.5 -lpthread -lgmp -ldl -lcrypt -lm
```

Comment: Are you running an X server? Vim is supposed to copy register `+` to the X server's "cut buffer" before exiting thus preserving the selection (see [How do registers + and \* interact with suspending Vim via Ctrl-Z?](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/31413)). Without X I'm not sure how it would be retained.

Comment: I use a standard desktop version of Debian with `tmux`, so I use an X server for graphics, right?

Comment: `tmux` just requires a terminal emulator, not any graphics per-se. I run `tmux` without X all the time. With a desktop manager, though, I'd think you have X but this is out of my realm of experience. Try [How to check if X server is running?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/637005)

Comment: @BLayer I'd say yes. From https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Clipboard#History, "In X10, cut buffers were introduced. These were limited buffers that stored arbitrary text and were used by most applications. However, they were inefficient and implementation of them varied, so selections were introduced. Cut buffers are long deprecated, and although some applications (such as xterm) may have legacy support for them, it is both not likely and not recommended that they be used."

Comment: also, I believe cut buffers only support ascii text

Comment: @BLayer When referring to “desktop manager” you mean “desktop environment” like GNOME or KDE?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

#### Solution

Install a [clipboard manager](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Clipboard_manager#Managers).

For example, I use [clipmenu](https://github.com/cdown/clipmenu/). I start it whenever X is started by putting this

```
CM_OWN_CLIPBOARD=1 clipmenud &
```

in my `~/.xinitrc`.

#### Why

Yours is a common misunderstanding when talking about X selections.

From [Arch Wiki: Clipboard](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Clipboard#Selections):

> According to the selection protocols, nothing is copied until it is pasted. For example, if you select some word in a terminal window, close the terminal and then want to paste it somewhere else, it will not work because the terminal is gone and the text has not been copied anywhere. If you want the word to be preserved after closing terminal window, consider installing a clipboard manager.

From [Ubuntu Wiki: ClipboardPersistence](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ClipboardPersistence#Why_does_this_happen.3F):

> The problem happens because Xorg takes a conservative approach to copying. It copies only a reference to the original data when the user performs a select or copy. It doesn't go and retrieve the actual data from the source program until the user requests a paste. It saves a lot of unneeded transfer of data this way, at the expense of having no way of retrieving data from a closed program that hasn't saved its clipboard somewhere else.

Comment: Thank you. But why is Xorg in play, when running Vim inside Tmux? I’m by no means an Xorg expert, but isn’t Tmux starting a terminal, not a graphical application rendered by Xorg?

Comment: @Shuzheng Tmux isn't relevant here: Vim is talking directly to the X11 server when you're using the `"*` and `"+` registers, not to or through the terminal process. (As with any X11 application, it uses the `DISPLAY` environment variable to determine how to contact the X11 server. An X11 application doing this need not be rendering anything on the screen; `xmodmap` is another example of a program that talks to the X11 server but uses only console/terminal I/O for its user interface.)

Comment: @cjs Thanks, so Vim is not talking to Tmux (terminal process). However, Vim is rendered by X11, since its enclosing terminal (e.g. `gnome-terminal`) is rendered by it?

Comment: @cjs Experimented with this on macOS and there what's copied to `"+` may still be yanked after Vim exists, despite no X11 server

Comment: Also, the output of `printenv DISPLAY` is `:0` meaning and X11 server is running?

Comment: @Shuzheng All you need to understand is that a terminal Vim, as a standalone program, may or may not connect to the X Window System if one is running. The possibility of connecting or not depends on how it was compiled and if you invoked with with the `-X` flag. If it does connect to X, then it does not matter if inside Tmux, Screen or a bare Xterm, since Vim will directly talk to X (e.g. for owning clipboard/primary), even though it is not responsible for drawing it's own X window.

Comment: [With a quick search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Display_server#Quartz_Compositor), I don't think MacOS uses the X11 protocol, so it is no surprise if it behaves differently.

Comment: is such behavior terminal-only? does it affect UE in window manager applications?

Comment: @Quasímodo Can you recommend another clipboard manager instead of `clipmenu` that's available for Debian?

Comment: @Shuzheng Vim is not rendered _directly_ by X11. Vim simply sends characters to stdout, both printable and "control" characters encoding commands like "clear the screen" or "move the cursor here." Traditionally those would go to a serial port connected to a video display terminal; an xterm receiving the characters instead simulates a terminal by displaying similar results in a graphical window. (Tmux is actually a _second_ layer of emulation between these, pretending to be a terminal to vim, and talking to another pretend terminal on its output.)

Comment: @cjs So, X11 finally renders xterm, i.e. `vim` -> `tmux` -> `xterm` -> `X11`?

Comment: @Quasímodo It's actually a little weird Vim doesn't save it's clipboard before exit as your Ubuntu reference describe (it lists `vim` as broken): *Freedesktop's ClipboardManager specification comes to the rescue. Gnome settings daemon, the component of Ubuntu that handles all copying and pasting by default, conforms by allowing applications to explicitly request to save their clipboard contents in a safe place. Applications conform by requesting a save before they exit. Everything gets squared away before a quit and we don't lose any data.*

Comment: @Quasímodo What's meant by `$CM_OWN_CLIPBOARD: take ownership of the clipboard`? Does that mean everything is directly copied to the clipboard without first using `clipmenu`?

Comment: @Shuzheng Yes, that the sequence. Keep in mind that all communications in that chain from vim through to xterm are simply sequences of bytes representing characters and control codes; xterm is actually the one that converts, e.g., a 0x63 byte to a set of dots or strokes on the screen representing the glyph `c`. (Tmux actualy dates from the days when all you had was a serial terminal with one 80x25 text screen; tmux is essentially a simple windowing system for character terminals. I'm not sure why people use that windowing system inside windows in the X11 windowing system.)